# Does a MongoDB query need explicit sort() call if data is retrieved from an index?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I am building a mongo database to store data that will be time stamped. Each document in my database has a time field:

```
{"time":<datetime-object>}
```

I have created an index for the `time` field as so:

```
self.db.test.create_index([("time", pymongo.ASCENDING)])
```

And have a query that requests only the time stamp information from the database:

```
self.db.test.find({'time':{'$gte':start, '$lte':end}}, {"time":1, "_id":0}).sort([("time", 1)])
```

I have read other questions/documentation that say using an index to get documents should return documents in sorted order since the index itself is already sorted, but all of the examples that I saw still had a direct call to `sort()` as part of the query. My question is, if I am specifically requesting only one field that I have an index for from the database, do I need to include the `sort()` method as part of my query, or will the documents be returned in sorted order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if I am specifically requesting only one field that I have an index for from the database, do I need to include the sort() method as part of my query, or will the documents be returned in sorted order?

In your example case of a [single field](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-single/#create-an-ascending-index-on-a-single-field) with an index where it is a [covered query](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/query-optimization/#covered-query), then the order returned would be the order from the index itself.

However, in the case of a multikey field with [multikey index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/indexes/#multikey-index) is not so. This is because multikey indexes cannot cover queries over array field(s).

It is recommended to specify [sort()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.sort/) regardless because:

- The [query planner](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/query-plans/) will discard the sort stage automatically if it's able to use an index. See also [Query Optimisation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/query-optimization/) and [Explain Results](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/explain-results/) for more information.
- Explicitly specifying `sort()` is not only going to protect your code against the unexpected (i.e. inconsistent values, etc) but also make the code readable.

You may also be interested in [Use Indexes to Sort Query Results](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/sort-results-with-indexes/#use-indexes-to-sort-query-results)